# How can i call flutter code from native platform?

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, dart

I have a difficulty developing MethodChannel.

I made a method "testMethod" which called from Unity project. like this.

```
private fun testMethod() :String{
    var testResult: String = "Failed"

    Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post{
        channel.invokeMethod(
            "testMethod",
            "testMethodChannel",
            object: MethodChannel.Result{
                override fun success(result: Any?) {
                    Log.d("Result", result.toString())
                    testResult = result.toString()
                }

                override fun error(errorCode: String, errorMessage: String?, errorDetails: Any?) {
                    Log.d("Result", "Error: $errorCode, $errorMessage, $errorDetails")
                }

                override fun notImplemented() {
                    Log.d("Result", "Not Implemented")
                }

            }
        );
    }
    
    return testResult
}
```

In order to set result to testResult, I have to wait the response of flutter code.
But I don't know how can I wait it.

Here is the flutter code.

```dart
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final MethodChannel _channel = const MethodChannel("com.example.test_method_channel");
  // final EventChannel _channel = const EventChannel("com.example.test_method_channel");

  @override
  void initState() {
    _channel.setMethodCallHandler((call) async {
      log(call.method);
      return "Success : ${call.arguments}";
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("Test Native Comm")),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: const [
            Text("Test Native Comm"),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried runBlocking, delay using while condition.